# Working around sitemap limitations

Tags: asp.net, navigation, sitemap

The documentation is clear: two nodes in the sitemap cannot point to the same file.  But I need to be able to do this (different roles run the same report). Does this mean I have to abandon sitemap? I hate to do that because I really like its other features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution, while still using the ASP.Net sitemap, would be to differentiate the 2 URLs by adding dummy querystring / anchor parameters. For eg.

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Report.aspx?x=1" title="Report 1"  description="Report 1" /> 
<siteMapNode url="~/Report.aspx?x=2" title="Report 2"  description="Report 1 with different name" />
```

OR

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Report.aspx#1" title="Report 1"  description="Report 1" /> 
<siteMapNode url="~/Report.aspx#2" title="Report 2"  description="Report 1 with different name" />
```

I personally prefer the querystring solution

Comment: Oh nice. It's a dodge but it's harmless. I'll use it.

I have a related question, regarding linking to an off-site page. Again, the rules say this isn't allowed, while my customer insists it be allowed. Is there a workaround?

And, also, since I'm relatively new here, should I post the above as a separate question? I do want to follow protocol.

Comment: @SkipKnox, there is something about adding external URLs to the sitemap in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227425.aspx), which says "In a site map, you can reference URLs that are outside of your ASP.NET application. However, access to a URL outside of the application cannot be tested by ASP.NET.. If you enable security trimming and you have site-map nodes that correspond to external URLs, set the roles attribute on those nodes to an asterisk (*), which will enable all clients to view the link even though ASP.NET cannot authorize access to the external link."

Comment: If you are concerned about the security trimming setting, you can probably have a page / HTTP handler within your application which can do the redirection to the external site. This is a more elegant solution if you want to capture how many users clicked on the external link. If these answers did solve your problem, it would be great if you can mark it as the answer and vote for it.